# Admob InterstitialAd event handler doesn't get called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm writing an Ad Controller in [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d). I found strange problem with event handlers related with interstital ads.

Method that I use to request interstitial:

```
private void GoogleRequestInterstitial(string gameID)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gameID))
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("GoogleAds - Game ID can't be NULL or EMPTY!");
        if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Game ID can't be NULL or EMPTY!");
    }

    var interstitial = new InterstitialAd(gameID);
    AdRequest request = null;

    if (CallbackMethod != null)
    {
        interstitial.AdFailedToLoad += InterstitialOnAdFailedToLoad;
        interstitial.AdClosed += InterstitialOnAdClosed;
        interstitial.AdClosing += InterstitialOnAdClosing;
        interstitial.AdLeftApplication += InterstitialOnAdLeftApplication;
        interstitial.AdLoaded += InterstitialOnAdLoaded;
        interstitial.AdOpened += InterstitialOnAdOpened;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarningFormat("GoogleAds - Don't forget to register callback!");
        if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Don't forget to register callback!");
    }

    if (DebugMode)
    {
        request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator) // Simulator.
            .AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b") // My test device.
            .Build();
    }
    else
    {
        request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    }

    interstitial.LoadAd(request);

    controller.StartCoroutine(GoogleShowAdWhenReady(interstitial));
}
```

Corutine:

```
private IEnumerator GoogleShowAdWhenReady(InterstitialAd interstitial)
{
    while (!interstitial.IsLoaded())
        yield return null;

    interstitial.Show();
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial : SHOW");
}
```

Here is whole event handlers region:

```
#region EventHandlers - INTERSTITIAL

private void InterstitialOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    CallbackMethod(WinzebraAdsController.WinzebraShowResult.Finished);
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "FINISHED");

    var obj = sender as InterstitialAd;
    obj.Destroy();
}

private void InterstitialOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    CallbackMethod(WinzebraAdsController.WinzebraShowResult.Failed);
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "FAILED !");

    var obj = sender as InterstitialAd;
    obj.Destroy();
}

private void InterstitialOnAdClosing(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial On Ad Closing");
}

private void InterstitialOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial On Ad Opened");
}

private void InterstitialOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial On Ad Loaded");
}

private void InterstitialOnAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial On Ad Left Application");
}

#endregion
```

Info:

- WinzebraAdsConsole is self-written "console" based on Text component.
- CallbackMethod is custom "global" callback and this is allways NOT NULL (checked before).

On first run i can see in self-written console that methods InterstitialOnAdLoaded and InterstitialOnAdOpened runs properly. But problem starts when im close interstitial and event InterstitialOnAdClosed doesn't get called. 
Additionally on second run of interstitial i get event InterstitialOnAdClosing but still not "OnClosed".

Is there any problem with my code? Anyone see that kind of problem before?

Screenshoots:

1. After first interstitial:

[image]

2. After second interstitial:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to define another Co-routine to wait will the ad is read to display, instead try this may fix your issue:

```
private void InterstitialOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial On Ad Loaded");

    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {    
        interstitial.Show();
        if (WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance != null) WinzebraAdsConsole.Instance.WriteLine(TagGoogleAds, "Interstitial : SHOW");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. It's really strange casue now interstitial didn't show up. Can it be related with application in debug stage - i mean application isn't published anywhere at the moment.

Comment: No need to publish for testing admob. Are you running on unity or in device ?

Comment: On device - Samsung S3 mini - android 4.2.2. I got newest Admob package from github and updated google play services included in project.

Comment: and what is the value of `DebugMode` ?

Comment: you said interstitial didn't show up.. did you get this message then "Interstitial : SHOW" ?

Comment: No, last log is from Banner Ad. And there are no any log from interstitial.